# Android studio no reconoce ningún objeto

Tags: java, android-studio

Hace unos días se actualizó Android Studio a la versión 4. Estuve trabajando bien, pero desde ayer al cargar cualquier proyecto me salen todos los objetos (String, int, etc) que no los reconoce.

He creado un proyecto nuevo y al ver la clase MainActivity le pasa lo mismo, no reconoce nada, ni los imports.

He hecho lo que se lee por los foros:
Clean un Rebuild
Clear Caché and Restart, 
etc

Pero no me funcionan.

Uso Windows 10, versión 1909.

Estoy perdido. ¿Alguna idea?
Saludos

**EDITO:**
He desinstalado completamente Android Studio (incluso borrando carpetas del HDD) y vuelto a instalar, y sigue lo mismo.

Comment: Si vas en Project / Settings, ves la buena JDK y las buenas configuracciones por SDK, Maven (u otro) etc.? Si te pone en rojo hasta String, parece ser que no tenga ni la JDK de base.

Comment: Si pincho en Tools--> SDK MANAGER no hace nada de nada (?¡?¡')...

Comment: No conozco Android Studio, pero sé que es un fork de IntelliJ lo cual utilizo a menudo. Cuando me pasa eso, suele ser un problema o de dependencias (Maven, Gradle o lo que sea no consiguen acceder a los repositories) o, en tu caso donde tambien las clases basicas no estan reconocidas, de la JDK. Intentaria buscar la soluccion con eso, a lo mejor vuelve a installar la JDK?

Comment: He instalado una version inferior 2.x.x y al actualizarla a 4.0 ya me funciona el SDK.
Sin embargo, ahora me dice que "This project uses AndroidX dependencies" y si las activo en gradle.properties me falla algo otra activity.
Yo no quiero usar AndroidX pero no sé cómo quitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que al actualizar Android Studio realices la invalidación de caché para que tu proyecto funcione adecuadamente con la nueva configuración.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Elimina el directorio /.idea y construye nuevamente el proyecto.

El error principal indicaría que no encuentra el SDK por lo tanto también revisa dentro del archivo `local.properties` que la ruta del Android SDK es correcta, ejemplo:

```
sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\jorgesys\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk
```

Comment: Eso tambien lo hice pero no funcionó.
Creo que tiene que ver con AndroidX pero no sé cómo arreglarlo. Gracias

Comment: Revisa la actualizacion de mi respuesta @Huno supongo que tienes instalado el Android SDK verdad?

Comment: Lo de borrar el directorio: .idea tambien lo hice. El camino al SDK tambien es correcto.

Al final, despues de varias desinstalaciones e instalaciones de varias versiones de Android, he conseguido que me funcione al menos la versión anterior de la APP y he creado un proyecto nuevo (que ahora no me da fallos) y he copiado manualmente las activity y los XLM y demas y espero conseguir que me funcione.
La verdad es que me es difícil saber qué es lo que hice mal....
Gracias por tu respuesta.Jorgesys.